# How to do asciidocify instead of markdownify in hugo go templates?

Tags: templates, go, asciidoc, hugo

In my hugo project I define a "description" attribute in a yaml config file.

```
description: >
    Some text ...
    Some more text ...
```

I use it in a html file and run it through the markdown preprocessor.

```
<p>{{ .description | markdownify }}</p>
```

As I normally use Asciidoc files I would prefer to have the sourcefiles in Asciidoc. But I didn't find a function like "asciidocify".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently (as of Hugo 0.16) an `asciidocify` or similar func, and I guess it will not be either, until we get native (Go) Asciidoc support in Hugo.

I'm the maintainer of Hugo.